# Remove duplicate element from vector of vectors c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm trying to remove a duplicated item from a bigger vector
Ex:

```
6 11  
7 8
6 16 17
```

I should get:

```
6 11  
7 8
16 17
```

What I have:

```
vector<vector<int>>B;
vector<vector<int>>::iterator b_list;
vector<vector<int>>::iterator b_it;
vector<int>::iterator b_list_it;
vector<int>::iterator b_it_it;
for (b_list = B.begin(); b_list != B.end()-1; ++b_list)
{
    for (b_it = b_list+1; b_it != B.end(); ++b_it)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < (*b_list).size(); ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < (*b_it).size(); ++j)
            {
                if ((*b_list)[i] == (*b_it)[j])
                {
                    if ((*b_list).size() > (*b_it).size())
                        {   
                            (*b_list).erase((*b_list).begin());
                        }
                        if ((*b_list).size() < (*b_it).size())
                        {
                            (*b_it).erase((*b_it).begin());
                        }
                }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

In this case erase() doesn't remove anything. Why could it be so? And what could be used instead of it?

Thank You!

Comment: Note that `erase()` affects the iterator stability.

Comment: You may want to spend some time studying the [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP has two dimensional vector.
Not sure if OP wants the data in sorted (unique can be used in that case)
But taking assumption they are not sorted a set is used as tracker .
Keeps a track of unique values .            `if (ret.second!=false)`
            `fogRow.push_back(s)`;A copy vector is used where every time unique values are there it is pushed in

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  ranged
//
//  Created by Hariom Singh on 9/9/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Hariom Singh. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >  val {{6,11},{7,8},{6,16,17}};
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >  uniquevalcopy;
    std::set<int> tracker;
    for ( const auto &row : val )
    {
        std::vector <int> fogRow;
        for ( const auto &s : row )
        {
            std::cout << s << ' ';
            auto ret = tracker.insert(s);
            if (ret.second!=false)
            fogRow.push_back(s);

        }
        uniquevalcopy.push_back(fogRow);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout<<"after removal"<<"\n";
    for ( const auto &row : uniquevalcopy )
    {
        for ( const auto &s : row )
        {
            std::cout << s << ' ';

        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
6 11 
7 8 
6 16 17 
after removal
6 11 
7 8 
16 17 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this much more easily by using the STL facilities as follows

```
vector<int> vec{1,2,3,5,2,3,8};
set<int> s(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend());
vec = vector<int>(s.cbegin(), s.cend());
```

I'm pretty sure this is going to be more efficient than any algorithm you're going to come up with.

Comment: You beat me to the fact they should just use sets. Good thinking. +1.

Comment: OP has two dimensional vector

Comment: it's clear that what can be done for a vector, can be done for a vector of vectors with a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "unique" function which returns the position of the last element being removed. The "unique" function removes all occurrences and just leaves a single instance of that.

An example is:

```
vector<int>::iterator it;
vector<int> nums = {1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1};

std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end()); //sort ascending
it = std::unique(nums.begin(), nums.end()); //remove occurrences

nums.resize(std::distance(nums.begin(), it)) //resize to remove missing empty slots in container

for(auto num : nums){
   std:cout<< num;
}
```

Output is 1235

Comment: Note that `std::unique` removes only consecutive duplicate elements. You need to sort the vector fist.

Comment: Thanks. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use iterators referencing beyond deleted position after vector::erase() call

Look e.g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/).

> Iterators, pointers and references pointing to position and beyond are invalidated, with all iterators, pointers and references to elements before position are guaranteed to keep referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call.